# How to use a Web-Server on android application?

Tags: android, webserver

I have written an Android app which now i want its users to access app data outside the mobile device through the LAN(Local area network) IP address, in other word, when users type LAN address like :

```
192.168.1.[any LAN IP]
```

Users should be able to see the app website which is in their android cellphone.

I can write a website and handle a web-server but my question is :

How can i use an web-server in my app?

Comment: use `WebView` : `webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.x/web"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at NanoHttpd to add a webserver to your app.

Comment: unfortunately It is very poorly documented and i use Eclipse and i don't know how to add it to Eclipse.

Comment: Dont understand. You add some .java files and done. To start you only need one file: NanoHTTPD.java.

Answer (score 0):

what is the language of your web-server?

you have the Web-Server in a local machine or a web Hosting?

Comment: The server should reside on mobile device.Java of course.